# Opera opening blank window with window.open on internal (intranet) network (tested with opera 11.50);document.write does not work

Tags: popup, opera, intranet, window.open, document.write

The following code works fine on www but opens a blank window in an internal network.  That is, it'll work on http://www.foobar.com, but it'll die on http://myserver.foobar.com, where myserver is a private-facing web server.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script Language="JavaScript">
      function OpenWindow()
        {
          var popup=window.open("","");
          popup.document.write("<H1>TEST</H1>");
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="button" onclick="OpenWindow();">
  </body>
</html>
```

FYI, the code above works in IE, FireFox, Chrome, and Safari on the internal network.  Only Opera (tested on version 11.50) doesn't like it.  It basically ignores document.write, I think.

Is this a bug with Opera?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in Opera 11.52 running on localhost (converted to a JSP and running in a tomcat container) and it works fine.

Some things to check:

- is your Opera set to block popups? (Ctrl+12 -> General -> Pop-ups)
- is your Opera set to notify you when it blocks popups? (Ctrl+F12 -> Advanced -> Notifications -> Show notification for blocked pop-ups)
- is your Opera set to block content from the domain you're having problems with, or are there "hidden" errors? (Right-click on page -> Edit site preferences...; then, look at your Pop-ups setting on *General* tab; tick "Open console on error" on *Scripting* tab; and check whether your proxy settings are correct on *Network* tab; finally, right-click on the page -> Block content -> Details..., and check whether anything might be blocked.
- are your proxy settings correct (internal server seems to suggest a corporate network which is typically behind a proxy)?
- is there a problem with your site certificate (often the case with intranet sites where you don't really need internal certificates)? (Ctrl+F12 -> Advanced -> Security -> Manage Certificates...

If it's none of the above, try posting your questions on the Opera forums, they're generally very helpful and very knowledgeable.

Cheers :-)